# Why is YTW (Yield-to-Worst) not available for some callable bonds?

Tags: united-states, investing, bonds, yield, municipal-bonds

E.g., I am looking at `67765QDG8` ("Oh St Wtr Dev Auth REV 5% 06/01/2023") on [Schwab](https://client.schwab.com/Areas/Trade/FixedIncomeSearch/FISearch.aspx/Municipals). It is callable but the yield to worse isn't indicated:

[image]

Bond details: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNt20.jpg ("Call Details: No Cash Call Identified").

From my understanding, since the bonds is callable, its yield to worse may be lower than the yield to maturity. Consequently, I'd like to know the yield to worse of this bond.

How can I find out the yield to worse (YTW) of a municipal bond when my broker fails to disclose it?

Comment: What's the call schedule? Are there any call dates left between now and maturity? If not, the YTM and YTW are the same. Again, this is a question specific to Schwab, so ask their support.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD "What's the call schedule?" what's a convenient way to find the call schedule? An answer doesn't have to use Schwab:  this question is not specific to Schwab.

Comment: If you cannot find it on Schwab and cannot compute it yourself you will need access to a different system like a Bloomberg terminal if you want to know YTW.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find more details if you click on the links in the table. If not, look for the prospectus.

Comment: @AKdemy you don't need a BBG terminal to find the basic facts of a muni

Comment: I see the screenshot in your edit, so look under Offering Documents...

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD It points to a few documents. I believe the most important is https://www.munifilings.com/munifilings/multiThreaded.do?method=DIRECT&fileType=IRIS&list=ep434 but as a bond neophyte it's not straightforward to infer the call schedule/conditions from it.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD still rather not so obvious to infer the call schedule/conditions from the PDF even when searching for "call" or "schedule".

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD reading is not the same as searching.  Always good to remember that documents are searchable, but easy to forget. Also, that doesn't always work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, Fidelity shows a YTW that's identical to the YTM. It also doesn't show a call schedule/dates, other than "extraordinary redemption", so there's no YTW to be calculated.

[image]

[image]

Looking at the [details on EMMA](https://emma.msrb.org/Security/Details/?id=67765QDG8) we find the [Offering Statement](https://emma.msrb.org/ER982886-ER769277-ER1170670.pdf)

Page 18:

[image]

and further on Page 19

[image]

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks! It helps guide people who aren't used to read bond prospectus. I was planning to reread it to make sure I got it right. From my first reading, it means the bond isn't callable anymore (last possible call was on Aug 3, 2019 + 90 days. I was also thinking about "It also doesn't show a call schedule/dates, other than "extraordinary redemption", so there's no YTW to be calculated.".

Comment: Yes, I didn't write it was callable on a set schedule. The only possible call is via the extraordinary redemption between  Aug 3, 2019 and Aug 3, 2019 + 90 days. "After 2019, it's subject to extraordinary redemption but it's not known if/when that will occur, so there's no meaningful YTW to be calculated" -> couldn't we take the worse case scenario to compute the YTW?

Comment: That'd help if you could indicate what is incorrect in my comment. From your screenshot " subject to extraordinary mandatory redemption by the Authority at any time during the ninety-day period following August 3, 2019", I understood that he only possible call is via the extraordinary redemption between Aug 3, 2019 and Aug 3, 2019 + 90 days. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, my first advice to you is to buy a dictionary. Most, if not all of your questions, stem from just not understanding the terms. Here's the basics on [callable bonds](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/investing-basics/glossary/callable-or-redeemable-bonds).

The bond can be called under certain conditions. For example, on specific schedule, or alternatively, any time or given other specific conditions. Depending on how the bond can be called, YTW may not be possible to calculate (because some conditions may not be known in advance).

You can find the information in the bond prospectus.

Why your broker doesn't show YTW to a specific bond - you'll have to ask the broker.

Comment: Thanks. My [dictionary](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/yield-to-worst-ytw) states "The yield to worst (YTW) can be defined as the minimum yield that can be received on a bond, assuming the issuer doesn’t default on any of its payments." Therefore, if some conditions may not be known in advance, wouldn't the YTW assumes the worse conditions possible (assuming the issuer doesn’t default)? ("Why your broker doesn't show YTW to a specific bond - you'll have to ask the broker": I'm instead asking "How can I find out the yield to worse (YTW) of a municipal bond when my broker fails to disclose it?")

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that still may not be calculable. Call Schwab and ask for details.

Comment: "that still may not be calculable": would you have an example? I just took Schwab as an example for the broker. My question is not specific to Schwab. My question is: "How can I find out the yield to worse (YTW) of a municipal bond when my broker fails to disclose it?"

Answer (score 0):

As per your attached screenshot for [Bond details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNt20.jpg), Schwab states that the bond is callable anytime with 30 day notice according to Schwab and displays it as callable. To find the yield to worst of an American callable bond, you would need to loop overall all potential call dates from today + 30 until maturity, compute the yield as if the call were exercised on this date, and find the worst yield possible. Most likely Schwab does not do that for American callable bonds as it's rather computationally expensive.

With regards to the bond itself, it is indeed only subject to extraordinary redemption. Insofar, Schwab is not displaying it correctly. In my opinion, if it claims it is callable, it should display a YTW as well.

With regards to callable above par, the bond traded below the redemption price of 115.546 ever since 2018, which means that yield to call (yield to extraordinary redemption) would have been above the YTM, making YTM the YTW in any case.

[image]